# Como ordenar os resultados de um ranking?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo, e nele preciso fazer um ranking de acordo com o tempo que o usuário levou para chegar ao final do jogo.

A minha dúvida é o seguinte, qual tipo de dado devo usar no meu banco de dados para poder organizar na hora de mostrar o ranking?

Tenho a variável do tempo ex : `"00:32:54"` porém ela é uma string, como vou fazer para conseguir organizar ela em um ranking?

Comment: Porque não usar o tipo [time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) ? O ranking seria simplesmente o tempo ordenado de forma decrescente? Se sim, é só ordenar na query mesmo.

Comment: Se você só tem um tempo por jogador, deve funcionar ordenar por string. Senão precisa usar `TIME` como estão te sugerindo.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4504/132

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar tanto o tipo TIME como o tipo INT ou DOUBLE/FLOAT/NUMERIC (dependendo do banco de dados). Implementação do tipo **TIME (MySQL)**:

```
CREATE TABLE rankingbytime (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(40),
  tempo TIME
);

INSERT INTO rankingbytime (nome, tempo) VALUES
('Fulano', '00:32:54'),
('Beltrano', '00:29:52'),
('Ciclano', '00:30:19'),
('Treuslano', '00:31:20'),
('Peuslano', '00:35:14');

SELECT id, nome, tempo FROM rankingbytime ORDER BY tempo ASC;
```

**Saída:**

```
| id |      nome |                     tempo |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|
|  2 |  Beltrano | January, 01 1970 00:29:52 |
|  3 |   Ciclano | January, 01 1970 00:30:19 |
|  4 | Treuslano | January, 01 1970 00:31:20 |
|  1 |    Fulano | January, 01 1970 00:32:54 |
|  5 |  Peuslano | January, 01 1970 00:35:14 |
```

Implementando o tipo **FLOAT (MySQL)**:

```
CREATE TABLE rankingbyseconds (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(40),
  tempo FLOAT(13,3)
);
INSERT INTO rankingbyseconds (nome, tempo) VALUES
('Fulano', 1974.523),
('Beltrano', 1792.584),
('Ciclano', 1819.287),
('Treuslano', 1880.518),
('Peuslano', 2114.261);

SELECT id, nome, tempo FROM rankingbyseconds ORDER BY tempo ASC;
```

<sub>As casas decimais do tipo *float* são os milésimos, caso for utilizar apenas segundas, pode utilizar o tipo de campo *INT* calculando apenas números inteiros que representariam o número de segundos.</sub>

**Saída:**

```
| id |      nome |    tempo |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |  Beltrano | 1792.584 |
|  3 |   Ciclano | 1819.287 |
|  4 | Treuslano | 1880.518 |
|  1 |    Fulano | 1974.523 |
|  5 |  Peuslano | 2114.261 |
```

#### [Exemplos funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d695d/1)

Você também pode usar o tipo DATETIME e gravar a data e hora inicial, e data e hora final, esse modelo fica pra você pesquisar.

Comment: Meu caro amigo, serei eternamente grato por você, nossa show de bola sua resposta e arrumou meu problema, MUITO OBRIGADO MESMO, SUCESSO PARA VOCÊ !

Answer (score 4):

Eu utilizaria o `PHP` para converter o tempo em segundos, e depois gravar só o numero no banco de dados, pode fazer um sistema de pontuação, exemplo 1 segundo é igual a 3 pontos, perdeu uma vida -100 pontos, depois multiplica os segundos por 3 e soma tudo no final.

Exemplo da função em `PHP` que converte tempo em segundos:

```
<?php 
function seconds_from_time($time) { 
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $time); 
    return ($h * 3600) + ($m * 60) + $s; 
} 

echo seconds_from_time("00:32:54");
```